# Quick Sort Algorithms - Many different ways of doing the same thing?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Am I correct in saying that there would be many ways to perform a Quick Sort?

For argument sakes, lets use the first textbook's numbers:
**20** 47 12 53 32 84 85 96 45 18

This book says to swap the 18 and **20** (in the book the 20 is red and the 18 is blue, so I've bolded the 20).

Basically it keeps moving the blue pointer until the numbers are:
18 12 **20** 53 32 84 85 96 45 47

Now it says (and this is obvious to me) that all the numbers to the left of the 20 are less than and all of the numbers to the right are greater than, but it never names the 20 as a "pivot", which is how most other resources talk about it. Then as all other methods state, it does a quick sort on two sides and then we end up with (it only covers sorting the right half of the list):

47 32 45 **53** 96 85 84 and the book ends. Now I know from the other resources that once all of the lists are in order they are put back together. I guess I understand this but am constantly confused by the one "Cambridge approved" textbook that differs from the second one. The second one talking about finding a pivot by picking the median.

What's the best way to find a "pivot" for a list?

Comment: The tag you suggest would not be appropriate for this site. See here for more information on tags: http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: That's one person's opinion. As high school teachers we are constantly not given enough resources or have to look across the internet for too many resources. We are teaching students how to program in an industry that is calling for more IT-trained people. Maybe Cambridge is the incorrect tag, how about "high school teachers" or "secondary teachers"?

Comment: If you want more opinions, including the people who run this site, look at Meta. It´s there somewhere. And the standard question for this case: Can someone be an expert knowing everything about "high school teachers"? No? Then it won´t get a tag. Experts about sorting algorithms are possible etc., but not teachers. It wouldn´t be useful. Nobody cares if you´re asking because you´re a teacher of Cambridge, people only care about the question. And no one will search "questions asked by teachers", but questions about eg. Quicksort.

Comment: The page I linked about tags indicates that tags should describe the *content* of the question.  If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it should not be used.  More detail [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is given in your textbook is similar to the pivot-based concept except that they haven't mentioned this terminology over there. But,anyways the concepts are the same.

> What's the best way to find a "pivot" for a list?

There's not a fixed way of selecting pivotal-element. You can select any of the element of the array---first,second,last,etc. It can also be randomly selected for a given array.

But, scientists and mathematicians generally talk about the median element which is the middle element of the list for the symmetry based reason,thereby reducing the recursive calls.

It is almost obvious that when you'll select the first or the last element of the array, there will be more number of recursive calls --- thereby moving closer to the worst case scenario. The more number of recursive calls will be framed to separately perform quick-sort on the two partitions.

Comment: Thank you and if I had enough points I'd rank your answer as useful!

Comment: @Chris-Thanks for the appreciation. Also, you can upvote my answer later when you gain 15 reputation, presently you have 8.

Answer (score 2):

**Theoretically - choosing the [median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) element** as the pivot guarantees least number of recursive calls, and guarantees `Theta(nlogn)` running time.

However, finding this median is done with [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) - and if you want to guarantee selection takes linear time - it needs [median of medians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) algorithm, which has poor constants.

If you chose the first (or last) element as pivot - you are guaranteed to get poor performance for sorted or almost sorted array - which is pretty likely to be your input array in many applications - so that's not a good choice either. So choosing the first/last element of the array is actually a bad idea.

A good solid solution to chose pivot - is **at random**. Draw a random number from `r = rand([0,length(array))`, and chose the r'th element as your pivot.

While there is a theoretical possibility for worst case here - it is:

1. Very unlikely
2. Hard for mallicious user to predict what is the worst case input, especially if the random function and/or seed is unknown to him.